# Android: Why does the calculated available space differ from Android's displayed available space

Tags: android

I have a question regarding the (free) available space in Android. If I open my Android settings, I can see that my external SD card has about 9GB of free space. But if I do some calculations in an Android application, I only get 1GB out of it. I'm using the following lines:

```
double freeSpace = stats.getAvailableBlocks() * stats.getBlockSize() / 1024;
```

and

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getUsableSpace();
```

What's the reason for this? I just want to get the available space on my SD card that I can use.

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory()` has nothing to do with an "external SD card" on most Android devices. You may be confused about the difference between [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I have been calculating the free space of my external storage (which is built in internally) instead of the free space of my removable storage (micro sd card). If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the solution! :) But how do I use getExternalFilesDirs() correctly?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you so much for those posts! It helped me a lot!! May I ask you some questions, sir? I'm checking the available free space calling getAvailableBytes() or getAvailableBlocks() * getBlockSize(). Do these methods return the total size including both Internal and External Storage?

Comment: And one more question. If I understood right, I don't think I need to check using the following code anymore for recent devices. String externalState=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(externalState)
|| Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(externalState)); Right?

Comment: @JenixGuy: "Do these methods return..." -- presumably, but I have never used them. "I don't think I need to check..." -- a tiny percentage of devices do have external storage on removable media, so ideally you handle the case where external storage is not available. I have never fully understood how the device gets into a `MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY` state, though, so I don't know whether that is still relevant. You may wish to ask  fresh Stack Overflow questions on those topics.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was putting the if statement even though I didn't know what exactly that means, just because many other people were doing it.. Thank you so much again for your reply :) BTW I did my own test, but don't get what's happening yet. Here are the results since you may wonder.

Comment: //A) On Real Hardware (Galaxy Note2 4.4.2)
External: 567574528, 567574528
Internal: 588546048, 588546048
Settings: 561MB

 //B) On Emulator (Genymotion, Galaxy Note2 4.3)
External: 17058758656, 17058758656
Internal: 36031201280, 4503900160
Settings: 4.2GB

Comment: Values in the former are from getAvailableBlocksLong() * getBlockSizeLong(), and values in the latter are from getAvailableBytes().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most modern Android devices, external storage is the part of the built-in flash that is accessible via a USB cable. While a long time ago external storage tended to be implemented via micro SD cards, that has not been the case in ~4 years and is rather rare today. Hence, `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is probably not what you want.

If your device is running Android 4.4+ — particularly if it shipped with Android 4.4+ — then if `getExternalFilesDirs()` returns 2+ entries, the second and subsequent locations are on removable storage. In principle, you could use those with your techniques from your question to try to determine the free space on the card. That being said, I have no idea if this works, as I have never tried it.

On the whole, removable media is mostly there for the benefit of device manufacturers and pre-installed apps, not ordinary SDK apps.

Comment: In case someone needs some code snippets, the following will lead you to the path of the current application on the last removable storage device: File[] listAllStorageDevices = getExternalFilesDirs(null);
  int lastStorageDevice = listAllStorageDevices.length - 1;
  String pathToSD = listAllStorageDevices[lastStorageDevice].toString();